# Can Long Integer store letters?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, database-performance

I ran 'Analyze Performance' feature in Access and it had an "idea" to improve performance; Access said I should convert items that are alphanumeric mixes that look like this `12BB1-DF740`§ from `text` data type into `long integer` (the specific name from the idea). Whether Access is right that this would improve performance is secondary to whether long integer can store letters at all.

*[§ About the data - the hyphen in the data provided to me is always present at that location; the letters are always A-F]*

From what I can tell, [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) is indicating that `Long` will only store numbers

> `Long` - Allows whole numbers between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647

- Am I conflating data types? (Further, when I pull up the design view, it only offers `number` as a data type; there is no `long` or `long integer`)
- Can `Long Integer` store letters?
- If my column is already populated, and I convert the data type, will I lose data?

Comment: You can convert a hex value (base 16) to a decimal value (base 10) and store the result in a long int (if the hex values don't overrun the long int).  However, your hex value (`12BB1-DF740`) really isn't a HEX value because it has a dash in it.  You cannot convert it to a long int and then convert it back to a HEX value with the dash in the same place without manually inserting the dash.  Why does it use 5 hex digits, a dash, and then 5 hex digits?  Seems like the app that maintains it needs it to be formatted in a very specific way -- that if converted to a long int will break the app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store those values by splitting them into 2 Long Integer columns.  Then when you need the original text form, concatenate their `Hex()` values with a dash between.

```
? Hex(76721) & "-" & Hex(915264)
12BB1-DF740
```

However I don't see why that would be worth doing.  Occasionally a performance analyzer suggestion just doesn't make sense to me; this is such a case.

Answer (score 2):

I've never run into this but it looks like it thinks your strings are hexadecimal numbers.

If you never have letters other than A-F then you could store them as longs and then convert back using the Hex() function but that seems mighty kludgy and something I'd avoid unless you're really desperate to eek out some performance.

Comment: thought the same too but '-' sign in example

Comment: @pkuderov Ah, I was thinking that was a seperator between two entries, but if not then yeah, you're right.

Comment: For context, there are currently 60 records, and I would only ever anticipate a max use case of 500; it seems that Hex()ing them might be more voodoo than its worth as I'm not currently having any performance issues and the records warehouse every six months or so

Comment: @kekekela If the values have the same view '#####-#####' where # from [0..9,A..F] then it still can be translated to hex. So I still like your idea)

Answer (score 1):

If it is in fact hexadecimal data, and it always has the same format so that the dash could just be added at the same place, then it would be possible to store the data numeric, and convert it into the hexadecimal notation when needed.

Ten hexadecimal digits represent 40 bits of data, so the `Long` type described at the w3schools page wouldn't do, as it's only 32 bits. You would need a data type that is a 64 bits, like a `double` or `bigint`. (The latter one might not be available in Access.)

However, that would only be any real gain if you actually do any processing of the data in the numeric form. Otherwise you would only save a few bytes per record, and you would need extra processing to convert to and from the numeric format.

If your table is already populated, you would have to read out the values, convert them, and store them back in the numeric form.